# Apple InAppPurchase

Tags: ios, ios5, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am facing a slightly weird issue here. for past 2 days My application is in "In Review" state in itunesconnect and my IAP are in rejected state. I dont even know why thy have been rejected as there is not link of resolution center appearing.
Have anyone faced similar issue?

please checkout the screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question and should be moved elsewhere.  Maybe http://superuser.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally, apple rejected the app and throw away reasons of some copyright material reason. They did not mention anything regarding in-app purchase which was already in rejected state :(

Answer (score 0):

Click on View Details and give space in some description and resubmit it again. You should be sure about

Comment: well... just providing sm space in description will make difference?

Answer (score 0):

Did you submit you IAP purchase for review when you submit your App on app store. Please check Status of your in app purchase in ituneconnect.

Comment: yes I did submit IAP with the app. Earlier their status was "Waiting for Review"